# how can i determine if i click the right movieclip/button? in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i am making a game wherein a pattern will appear and the user must click among the items what the pattern has shown example pattern: eraser, pencil, stapler, clip.

so if the user clicked pencil first instead of eraser the game will reset.

also how can i shuffle the items, is it possible just by the codes? i made (5 pencils, 3 erasers, 2 staplers, 6 clips, 3 ballpen, 5 glue, and 4 liquid eraser), or do i need to make every frame and manually shuffle them?

I made the program with the pattern: clip, eraser, glue, clip
what i done is give the pattern a value of 12
and then the value of items:pencil = 1, eraser = 2, clip = 3, glue = 4, stapler = 5, liquid eraser = 6, ballpen = 7,

the problem is anything i click as long as it create a value of 12 the user wins, that is why i want to make a detection if the item that is clicked is correct.

```
var total = 0;
var gattotal = 0;
var rndNum = 0;
pattern.visible = false;

//for random number
function randomNumbers(min:Number,max:Number) {
var Results:Number=Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;
return Results;
}

function determineWin() {
if (rndNum == 1){
    total = 12;
}

if (rndNum == 2){
    total = 16;
}

if (rndNum == 3){
    total = 7;
}
if (rndNum == 4){
    total = 15;
}
}

pushme.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, begin);

function begin (event:MouseEvent): void {
rndNum = randomNumbers(1,4);
pattern.visible = true;
trace(rndNum);

if (rndNum== 1){
    pattern.gotoAndStop(1);
}

if (rndNum == 2){
    pattern.gotoAndStop(2);
}

if (rndNum == 3){
    pattern.gotoAndStop(3);
}

if (rndNum == 4){
    pattern.gotoAndStop(4);
}

}


//to know if the pencil is clicked
this.pencil1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
this.pencil2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
this.pencil3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
this.pencil4.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
this.pencil5.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);

function pen(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var button:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
gattotal = gattotal + 1;
trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
event.target.visible = false;


if (gattotal == total){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
 }

 this.eraser1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, erase);
 this.eraser2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, erase);
 this.eraser3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, erase);


 function erase(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
 var buttons:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
gattotal = gattotal + 2;
 trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
event.target.visible = false;

if (gattotal == total){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
  }

 this.stapler1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, staple);
 this.stapler2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, staple);

 function staple(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
 var buttons1:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
gattotal = gattotal + 5;
 trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
event.target.visible = false;

if (gattotal == total){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
 }

 this.clips1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clip);
 this.clips2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clip);
 this.clips3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clip);
 this.clips4.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clip);
 this.clips5.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clip);
 this.clips6.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, clip);

 function clip(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
 var buttons2:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
gattotal = gattotal + 3;
 trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
event.target.visible = false;

if (gattotal == total){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
 }

this.glue1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, glue);
this.glue2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, glue);
this.glue3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, glue);
this.glue4.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, glue);
this.glue5.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, glue);

function glue(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var buttons3:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
gattotal = gattotal + 4;
trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
event.target.visible = false;

if (gattotal == total){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}

this.ballpen1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, bpen);
this.ballpen2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, bpen);
this.ballpen3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, bpen);

function bpen(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var buttons4:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
gattotal = gattotal + 7;
trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
event.target.visible = false;

if (gattotal == total){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
 }

this.liquidErase1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, leraser);
this.liquidErase2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, leraser);
this.liquidErase3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, leraser);
this.liquidErase4.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, leraser);

function leraser(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var buttons5:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
gattotal = gattotal + 6;
trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
event.target.visible = false;

if (gattotal == total){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
 }
```

the code is long and unorganized so i really don't want to post it :(

Comment: Could you edit your post and add in the code you have written thus far? It makes it much easier to help you, also are you writing your code on the timeline or in class files?

Comment: i used timeline and i'll post the codes

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you add a `MouseEvent.CLICK` listeners to each object on the stage, and in each object's listener function you add 1 to the variable `gattotal`. Then if `gattotal` equals `total` you go to a different frame. You have to come up with a way to differentiate between the different objects your clicking. For instance you have `pencil`, `glue`, `clips`, ... So add booleans in your code so that when you choose which object you want to be clicked, say `pencil`, you can make sure it's a `pencil` being click. Because in your code if you click anything it raises `gattotal`. Why not choose which object you want to be clicked via an `int`. Then when you go to add listeners to each object just encompass that process into if statements so that you only add listeners to the object you want clicked.

ie.)

```
// top of code
var objChosen:int = 1; // choose which object to be clicked

// [code]

// only add event listeners to the object you want clicked
if(objChosen == 1) {
    this.pencil1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
    this.pencil2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
    this.pencil3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
    this.pencil4.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);
    this.pencil5.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, pen);

    function pen(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var button:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
        gattotal = gattotal + 1;
        trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
        event.target.visible = false;


        if (gattotal == total){
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
     }
} else if(objChosen == 2) {
    this.eraser1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, erase);
    this.eraser2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, erase);
    this.eraser3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, erase);


    function erase(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var buttons:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
        gattotal = gattotal + 2;
        trace('total gathered value: ' + gattotal);
        event.target.visible = false;

        if (gattotal == total){
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
}
```